# SQL getting result from one table to query in another

Tags: join

I have two tables one contains a list of planes airports. The other contains a mapping from the planeID to the airlines.

Table: plane_dist

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| PlaneID  | AirportID | Time   |
+----------+-----------+--------+
| P234567  | A12312    | 1.2    |
| P234567  | A12315    | 1.1    |
+----------+-----------+--------+
```

Table: plane_mapping

```
 +----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
 | PlaneID  | Airline            | AirportID | Location           |
 +----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
 | P234567  | American Airlines  | A12312    | Los Angeles        |
 | P234566  | Delta Airlines     | A12315    | San Diego          |
 +----------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

Given an Airline I need to return the places of the airports.

Always returns an empty set:

```
 SELECT plane_dist.Time, plane_mapping.Airline 
 FROM plane_dist JOIN plane_mapping 
    on plane_dist.AirportID = plane_mapping.AirportID 
 WHERE 
    plane_dist.PlaneID=
    (SELECT DISTINCT PlaneID FROM plane_mapping WHERE Airline=('American Airlines'));
```

Two queries separately and they return the expected results:

```
SELECT plane_dist.Time, plane_mapping.Airline 
     FROM plane_dist JOIN plane_mapping 
        on plane_dist.AirportID = plane_mapping.AirportID 
     WHERE 
        plane_dist.PlaneID=('P234567');

SELECT DISTINCT PlaneID 
FROM plane_mapping WHERE Airline=('American Airlines');
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT plane_dist.Time, plane_mapping.Airline 
FROM plane_dist JOIN plane_mapping 
on plane_dist.AirportID = plane_mapping.AirportID 
WHERE Airline='American Airlines'
```

through your `JOIN` clause all columns of the plane_mapping table will be available for your `WHERE` clause.

Your original condition through the subquery was too complicated and it would probably return more than one results and that is not valid.

Comment: I wrote that almost 10 minutes ago ;)

Comment: Yeah, just discovered it, sorry.  I was typing away on my old iPod and did not notice it popping up in the meantime. OP will surely give you the deserved points for it. ;-)

Comment: Nah, no worries, I was just saying. Let's see who gets luckier. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understood, but it seems like you're overcomplicating it.

This query should return the times for given airlines:

```
SELECT plane_dist.Time, plane_mapping.Airline 
FROM plane_dist 
JOIN plane_mapping 
ON plane_dist.AirportID = plane_mapping.AirportID 
WHERE Airline=('American Airlines');
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a nested select here, the join is actually combining the columns of the two tables so you can simply filter for the airline in the where clause :

```
   SELECT plane_dist.Time, plane_mapping.Airline 
  FROM plane_dist JOIN plane_mapping 
on plane_dist.AirportID = plane_mapping.AirportID 
 WHERE 
plane_mapping.Airline = 'American Airlines'
```

Comment: can u clarify the issue??